Any mistake in programm? Called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
I have a problem with input and output. My code in Visual Studio don't throw any errors, but the platform, where i try to send the code, throw Runtime Error.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi

Input:
5
[05:00 a.m.]: Server is started
[05:00 a.m.]: Rescan initialized
[01:13 p.m.]: Request processed
[01:10 p.m.]: Request processed
[11:40 p.m.]: Rescan completed
Output: 2

My Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    string s;
    int n, hh, mm;
    fin >> n;
    vector<string>A;
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        string s;
        getline(fin, s);
        if (s != "") A.push_back(s);
    }
    fin.close();
    int days = 1;
    vector<int>t;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        hh = stoi(A[i].substr(1, 2));
        mm = stoi(A[i].substr(4, 2));
        string x = A[i].substr(7, 1);
        int time = hh * 60 + mm;
        if (time == 0) days++;
        if (x == "p" && time != 720) time += 720;
        t.push_back(time);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < t.size(); i++) {
        if (t[i] < t[i - 1]) days++;
    }
    fout.open("output.txt");
    fout << days;
    fout.close();
}

Idk when stoi accept the wrong param.

OT: Change the first loop to std::string s; for (int i = 0; i < n+1 && std::getline(fin, s); i++) { A.push_back(s); }

More related to your problem, please [edit] your question to tell us the full and complete assignment (copy-pasted as text). Include all requirements, limitations, constraints, as well as example input and output. For example, why i < n+1 in that first loop condition?

Re. "Idk when stoi accept the wrong param": why not use a debugger to find out?

@G.M. I debug in VS, each step stoi have acceptable param (example "00", "05".

@Someprogrammerdude, i set n +1, cauz in the first iterate i have the empty string, i often have this problem while use getline(cin, s)

i often have this problem while use getline

Note that the first item read from input.txt is with fin >> n; where n is an int.  Where is that integer in the example input.txt file you've shown?

@G.M. forget to paste here, in the first row stay n = rows count;
5

Can't replicate https://godbolt.org/z/Kozr1YTTW

Why write time parsing code yourself when there is std::chrono::from_stream. Also manually calling close on a stream is not necessary, just let the stream go out of scope (and the destructor will take care of the resources. Read up on RAII, which is a very important C++ concept)

@Eljay it's fine, it's convert to 8;9.

It appears there is trouble handling the noon hour (e.g., 12:34 p.m.) and the midnight hour (e.g., 12:34 a.m.).  I was unable to reproduce the problem with the provided input.

@Eljay yeah, the task expect to handle these, i understood the problem, but have a trouble with input.

Work for me, thanks @Someprogrammerdude
    getline(fin, s);
    n = stoi(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1 && std::getline(fin, s); i++) {
        A.push_back(s);
    }


Since you're apparently trying to parse a time, it's probably easiest to use std::get_time. Ideally, you'd get them to change the format ever so slightly, so your input would look like this:
[05:00 am]: Server is started
[05:00 am]: Rescan initialized
[01:13 pm]: Request processed
[01:10 pm]: Request processed
[11:40 pm]: Rescan completed

With this input, you can do something like this:
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {

        std::stringstream buffer(line);        
        std::tm timestamp;

        buffer >> std::get_time(&timestamp, "[%I:%M %p]: ");

        std::cout << "Timestamp: " << std::put_time(&timestamp, "%R\n");
    }

If you can't get them to change the format, perhaps you can use something like sed to do the job. Lacking even that, you can write a little function to "fix" it, something like this:
void fix_ampm(std::string &s) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> fixes {
        { "a.m.", "am"},
        { "p.m.", "pm"}
    };

    for (auto const &[find, rep] : fixes) {
        auto pos = s.find(find);
        if (pos != std::string::npos) {
            s.replace(pos, find.size(), rep);
        }
    }
}

In theory, you can write a locale facet to parse the required format, but unless you're going to use this specific format quite a bit, that's probably more trouble than it's worth.
